# Creating new HDFS in CDH4

Tags: ubuntu, mapreduce, cloudera, hadoop-yarn

I have installed CDH4 following the instructions in CDH4-Quick-Start.pdf for ubuntu. Three directories were created by default in /var/lib namely: hadoop-hdfs, hadoop-mapreduce, hadoop-yarn. Since I don't have much space in this partition I want to have at least the hdfs in another partition. I have stopped the hdfs and changed the parameters in hdfs-site.xml pointing to a directory in the new partition. I ve formatted and restarted hdfs but it was still the old directory that had been formatted. Now I don't have access to the server too.

What is the right procedure to create or move the 3 directories to another location? How can I fix the problem with the server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cloudera with cloudera manager then just go to the hdfs service configuration page and set the

**dfs.data.dir**

If you wanna do it manually just simply edit the hdfs-site.xml and change the value of this property  to your desired location it will set the data directory of your hdfs to this location.